# Creating WebService based on Sockets C#

Tags: c#, winforms, sockets

I have a `System.Net.Sockets` based server (which is currently running as a console application). I have clients which are Windows Forms. Is it possible to make my server application a socket-based webservice and host it on IIS?

Comment: But the IIS already is socket-based?!

All Web Service run over socket and implement http protocol

Comment: Very unclear what you expect from IIS hosting if you plan to use your own sockets communication.

Comment: I want to convert my application to socket-based webservice. That is, it must retain the capability of  asynchronous bidirectional communication between the server and client. I understand we can create a WCF service using nettcp binding and binary message format but it will loose the aysnc bidirectional communication functionality and I will only able to do server to client communication based on callbacks. So my question is, is it possible to convert the socket-based application to a socket based webservice

Comment: It will take me hours to really answer this question fully.  There is really no difference between a socket based application and a WCF application at the application level if the code is written properly.  A server is a slave application that responds to commands from a client.  A client is a master and sends commands to a server and waits for a response before proceeding.  The WCF application handles the application level communications.  The async bidirectional communications is done at the socket layer of the connection which is automatically handled by a WCF (you just don;t see it).